# Why can I not put statements into class scope?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, self-reference

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int val;
    struct Node *link;
    (*link).val = 12; // error
};

int main()
{
    struct Node *link=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    (*link).val = 15; // OK
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting an error when trying to access `(*link).val` inside the `struct`, while the same thing is working just fine in the `main` function?

Comment: First of all you should read about the -> operator.  Second, you can't put any definitions inside a struct. You need a constructor. And a decent book.

Comment: Assignments are only allowed in functions (like main). You can *initialize* members, like `int i = 0;`, which is not an assignment (despite the =). Also, `*link` has a second problem here  in that it points nowehere.

Comment: For starters, you can write `(*link).val` as `link->val`. They are semantically identical but much nicer to read. Secondly, you are not initializing `link` at all, so all your accesses are undefined behavior.

Comment: You are writing one of C or C++, not both at the same time. Good practice for writing code is different between the two. Which language are you actually using?

Comment: BTW: Your code in `main` is also invalid because `link` does not point to valid memory. You must assign a valid address first.

Comment: Voting to close this as unclear since C and C++ are very different here (as well, they tend to be almost everywhere). Without clarifying which language you are using, the question is both unclear and too broad. If you wish to learn the answer in both languages, please ask two separate questions.

Comment: What do you want the statement inside `struct Node` to do, exactly?

Comment: Note that aside from the fact that you're doing something the language doesn't allow, the `link` in `main` and the `link` in the declaration of `Node` are two different things, and in the latter case `link` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

You may declare members of a structure but you may not use statements (in C++ there can be declaration statements)  within a structure declaration in C and C++ like for example that

```
(*link).val=12;
```

A structure declaration may contain only declarations.

And in C opposite to C++ even member declarations may not have initializers. That is you may not write in C

```
struct Node
{
    int val = 12;
    struct Node *link;
};
```

Pay attention to that this code snippet

```
struct Node *link;
(*link).val=15;
```

invokes undefined behavior because the pointer `link` is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value.

Instead you could write for example

```
struct Node node;
struct Node *link = &node;
(*link).val=15;
```